# Does Blender support importing/exporting REDlog color format?

Tags: export, import, video, color-management

I'm a VFX supervisor for a student film, and they are filming with a RED camera with [REDlog](http://www.red.com/learn/red-101/redlogfilm-redgamma).  I haven't found a sure answer anywhere, so I want to confirm: can [REDlog](http://www.red.com/learn/red-101/redlogfilm-redgamma) video/color be *preserved* when imported into Blender (as the effect background) and exported with the effect applied as an image sequence?  If so, what methods do I need to do to ensure that that happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not as video, given that Blender will only import video at a down bitted 8 bits per channel, and potentially dubiously at that.

If you export to a proper still format such as a TIFF, not DPX as Blender's DPX code has been horribly broken for years, you can. This would require an OCIO stanza to properly convert it to the reference space.

Other option is to output a scene referred linear EXR with REC.709 primaries, or in the native RED gamut and write a simple OCIO stanza to handle the conversion.

> can REDlog video/color be preserved when imported into Blender (as the
>   effect background) and exported with the effect applied as an image
>   sequence?

It is impossible to preserve a wider gamut in a smaller gamut if you intend to conduct any manipulations on the pixels. This is a bit of a tricky area so I'll leave it at that to avoid boring you into submission. By default, Blender uses a REC.709 based reference space, and almost every single camera sensor on the market can record a wider gamut than the REC.709 / sRGB reference lights can represent. The only way around this is to use a wider reference space, and that is another topic altogether.

Comment: Will ffmpeg read RED? EDIT: I guess the RedCine X Pro utility is still available to convert the files?

Comment: RedCine X Pro is available, so I have that for conversions.  I just wasn't sure if there was a more native way.  I would prefer doing image sequences anyway, since it's more manageable. 
 Sorry, OCIOs are beyond me.  What are those exactly, and how would I create/modify those?  A good reference link would be fine if it's too much for here :)

Comment: Use RedCine to convert to scene referred EXRs, in REC.709 and you are good to go. OCIO is the colour management library for Blender. Be sure to set REC.709 (at D65), or your colour primaries won't line up with your CGI. Half float is more than enough. If you are supervising, you really should take the time to learn these things.

Comment: I jumped into the supervisor role fairly recently, so I'm trying to catch up.  I've been studying color spaces before now, but apparently not enough.  Thank you so much :)

Comment: Feel free to email or ping me if you encounter issues. The key thing to strive for is a scene referred model throughout your pipeline. It will make the work infinitely easier and far more seamless.